# Python Event Dispatcher

Tags: python, event-handling

This code creates a singleton event dispatcher. It's called like this:

> ```
> eventDispatcher = Event()
> eventDispatcher.on("event", handler)
> eventDispatcher.trigger("event", 5)
> ```

I'm wondering if this is "the python way," or if it could be improved? Especially the class, I'm not sure about creating a new object for every use of the dispatcher.

```
class Event():
    events = {}

    def on(self, event, func):
        if event not in self.events.keys():
            self.events[event] = []

        self.events[event].append(func)

    def trigger(self, event, *args, **namedArgs):
        if event in self.events.keys():
            for func in self.events[event]:
                func(*args, **namedArgs)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Checking items in dictionnary

There is no need to call `keys` when checking for dictionnary membership. Much like there is no need of `True` in `if my_bool == True`.

## on

Checking if a key exist and set it to a default value otherwise is so common that you have 2 standard ways of doing it: `dict.setdefault(...)` or using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

## trigger

Since `KeyError` should normaly not happen, you can use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach by using `try...except` instead of `if`. It's a tiny bit faster if exceptions are quite rare. Moreover, by using `defaultdict` you are guaranteed that every access to an item will be valid, thus eliminating the need to check membership of any key.

## class

Since the only state you need is the one of the class, and in order to avoid instanciating to call methods, you can use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)s and call them with `Event.on(...)` and `Event.trigger(..)`.

## Proposed alternative

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Event():
    __events = defaultdict(list)

    @staticmethod
    def on(event, func):
        Event.__events[event].append(func)

    @staticmethod
    def trigger(event, *args, **namedArgs):
        for func in Event.__events[event]:
            func(*args, **namedArgs)
```

Comment: Is there a reason two underscores are used with the events variable? (Rather than just one.)

Comment: @jayshua It is to trigger [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) to better emphasize that anything related to `__events` is `Event`'s business. You can use one or no underscore if you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Very minor note, but the normal Python names are `args` and `kwargs` (ie. Keyword Arguments).

```
def trigger(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: This should be a comment to the previous answer—not posted as its own answer.

Comment: @Zearin It's not related to the other answer, it's a separate note.